# Add multiple filter to search in Whoosh

Tags: python, whoosh

Faced with an issue. I need to create multiple filters to search in Whoosh. I tried to add `filter` in `search` like that

```
qp = qparser.QueryParser("content", myindex.schema)
user_q = qp.parse(query_string)
filter = And(list of Term)
results = s.search(user_q, filter=filter)
```

but it doesn't work. What can be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem could be in this:

`filter = And(list of Term)`

Check my answer here for the general recipe of adding multiple filters:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/72566461/4882462